# C++ Compiling Static Arrays of Unknown Type

Tags: c++, arrays, static-memory-allocation

Here is my code:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    class my_array {
    public:
        const T& at(std::size_t index) const
        {
            if(index>N) throw std::out_of_range("Index is wrong. Try again");
            return data[index];
        }
        
        ...

        my_array()
        {
            T data[N];
        }
        ~my_array()
        {
            delete[] data;
        }

    private:
        T* data;
    };
```

In the my_array() method I want to create a static array of type T, but I don't really understand how. For example, this way doesn't work.

I tried to do it the way I wrote above, I also tried to use typedef, though I may have done it wrong, but none of the ways worked.

How do I make it work?

Comment: "_I want to create a static array of type T_": What exactly do you mean with that? Where do you want the elements of the array to be stored? In the `my_array` object itself? If so, then the `data` member should just be an array type of the correct size instead of a pointer type and then there is no point in having `delete[]` (or any destructor declaration at all).

Comment: Why not use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: Side note: `index > N` should be `index >= N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is to create an array on the stack, just like `std::array`? If so, you can do it just like this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class my_array {
public:
    const T& at(std::size_t index) const
    {
        if (index >= N) throw std::out_of_range("Index is wrong. Try again");
        return data[index];
    }

    my_array() = default;
    ///~my_array() = default;    // dont write this

private:
    T data[N];
};
```

Note that you should not call `delete` on the array, because you didnt allocate memory with `new`.
Since there is no memory allocation with `new` going on here, you can just create an empty constructor and destructor, or specify it with `my_array() = default;` like I did.

As some comment already said, you could be accessing an element out of bounds in your `at()` method. Use `index >= N` instead (arrays go from 0 to N-1).

By the way you can just open the file `array` from the STL and take a look at its implementation. They have defined their data like this `_Ty _Elems[_Size];`.

---

**Edit:**

As the comments on this answer state, you shouldnt be defining a destructor for the class, if its gonna be empty anyways. With writing something like `~my_array() = default;` or `my_array(){}` and not specifying a move constructor, the data will always be copied instead of moved.

Comment: In this case `~my_array() = default;` is harmful and should be removed. It forces the class to always be copied, even when you try to move it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thaught myself some c++ and never heard of that. What exactly do you mean with its beeing copied always? Like if I create a move construcor, it is still going to pick the copy constructor?

Comment: @Joel Normally the compiler would define a move constructor and move assignment implicitly. However, declaring _any_ destructor whatsoever suppresses that.

Comment: So either one should not declare any destructor at all (rule-of-zero) or otherwise make sure to declare (and default, delete or explicit define as appropriate) all other special member functions (rule-of-five).

Comment: Here's an example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rv5MqeGrK Only Clang warns about this, and only with `-Wdeprecated` (copy operations themselves not being removed is deprecated).

Comment: I just tried it with this `my_arary` class in Visual Studio and yeah it did get copied. However there was no warnign. I usually wrote `= default` in most of my destructors when I didnt have to clean up anything and never noticed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote, so I wrote a thank you in the comments)